# OWASP Rules and Graphql

Tags: graphql

We have a apollo graphql server that sits behind a azure gateway. The gateway applies a large number of standard owasp rules which it applies to the body of the graqhql query post.

Due to the data in the graphql post, many OWASP rules get triggered that are false positives.

The question is should the OWASP rules be applied to the body of the post? I don't believe there is a risk of OWASP type attacks contained in the body of a graphql post, but how can I be sure??

Comment: What rules of OWASP are triggering a false positive in your requests? GraphQL requests are nothing more than a POST request but you can’t simply neglect the body of any request. Can you be more specific about the requests causing these issues?

Comment: We are using CRS 3.1 rule set, and here are some of the rules that are triggered by the body of graphql request

REQUEST-942-APPLICATION-ATTACK-SQLI
942190 Detects MSSQL code execution and information gathering attempts
942200 Detects MySQL comment-/space-obfuscated injections and backtick termination
PLus a number of other SQL rules. 

REQUEST-930-APPLICATION-ATTACK-LFI
930100 Path Traversal Attack (/../)
930130 Restricted File Access Attempt

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? We have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We ended up removing the checks on the body of the graphql request.